# One Model, Multiple ViewModel(?) Variations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm pretty new to the MVC scene and also haven't dealt with a scenario like this before now.  I have looked around the web for something to point me in the right direction but nothing seems to put into a context I understand fully.

I'm not sure if this applies to this scenario but I currently am not using any sort of AutoMapper.  This project is using MVC5/EF6.

Model

```
public class Unknown
{
    public int UnknownID { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReceivedDate { get; set; }
    public int SetuptypeID { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string RequestedBy { get; set; }
    public string ResultID { get; set; }
    public string RoutingNum { get; set; }
    public string TransAcctNum { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string SettleRoutingNum { get; set; }
    public string SettleAcctNum { get; set; }
    public string BillingRoutingNum { get; set; }
    public string BillingAcctNum { get; set; }
    public string PointName { get; set; }
    public string PepApplName { get; set; }
    public int RequestTypeID { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public virtual SetupType SetupType { get; set; }
    public virtual RequestType RequestType { get; set; }
}
```

SetupType 'Unknown' requires all fields

SetupType 'Internal' requires:

- UnknownID
- ReceivedDate
- SetuptypeID
- ClientName
- RequestedBy
- ResultID
- RoutingNum
- TransAcctNum
- RequestTypeID
- IsDeleted

SetupType 'ServiceVendor' requires:

- UnknownID
- ReceivedDate
- SetuptypeID
- ClientName
- RequestedBy
- ResultID
- Company
- SettleAcctNum
- BillingAcctNum
- RequestTypeID
- IsDeleted

There is another SetupType that has the same fields as 'Internal'
There are 10 other SetupType variations

Fields UnknownID, ReceivedDate, SetupTypeID, ClientName, RequestTypeID, and IsDeleted are in all SetupTypes.

I feel like setting up a separate ViewModel for each one listing out all the fields needed goes against the DRY principal.  What would be a good way to represent these SetupTypes?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: I need to be able to reference these individual setup types in multiple places within the application.  I'd like the setup type specific requirements to be housed in one location.  So for instance, one setup type might want a field name displayed differently.

Comment: Am I just over thinking this and a bunch of ViewModels is really the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do think multple ViewModels is the way to go here. If you feel bad about violating DRY, you can introduce an inheritance hierarchy and store the common logic in the base class and setuptype-specific logic (like your example of a field appearing differently for setup type = 'internal') in one of the derived classes.